# What's the point of "sep" in echo program in The Go Programming Language book?

Tags: go

Source: https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch1/echo1/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var s, sep string
    for i := 1; i < len(os.Args); i++ {
        s += sep + os.Args[i]
        sep = " "
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Here is the echo program from the  The Go Programming Language book. It basically echoes whatever you type in the console after you run the program.

What is the point of `sep` string variable?

The program seems to run perfectly fine without and concatinating this way.

`s += os.Args[i]` instead of `s += sep + os.Args[i]`

Comment: It *runs* if you take out `sep`, but did you compare the output?

Comment: Yes, there's seems to be no difference in the ouput. I wonder if the author wanted to demonstrate some subtle point about go language using `sep` here but I am not sure.

Comment: If you only passed it one argument, pass it some more this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command line (Terminal or CMD.exe), `cd` to folder with this file and execute:

```
go run main.go a b c
```

Output will be:

> a b c

Then, remove the `sep` variable from code and run it from command line again. New output will be:

> abc

Therefore,`sep` variable is used as separator - it adds blank space between two command line arguments passed to main function on application startup

Answer (score 3):

sep makes sure that there is a space between words and not at the beginning or end.

That's why it's a variable